# How can I extract the names of all fields of a specific type from an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an interface like this:

```typescript
interface SomeInterface {
    field1: string;
    field2: number;
    field3: string;
    field4: SomeOtherType;
}
```

I'd like to have a type that can extract all the keys who's values are a specific type:

```typescript
type ExtractFieldsOfType<Obj extends {}, Type> = // implementation

ExtractFieldsOfType<SomeInterface, string> // "field1" | "field3"
ExtractFieldsOfType<SomeInterface, number> // "field2"
ExtractFieldsOfType<SomeInterface, SomeOtherType> // "field4"
```

Is it possible to write something like this? I'm writing a function that operates on an object by key name, but it should only allow keys with specific values. So it'd be nice to express that through the type system.

Comment: Simply use as map.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it in TypeScript 2.8, with conditional types.

I created support type `AllowedFieldsWithType` to make cleaner implementation.

```
type AllowedFieldsWithType<Obj, Type> = {
    [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends Type ? K : never
};

type ExtractFieldsOfType<Obj, Type> = AllowedFieldsWithType<Obj, Type>[keyof Obj]

type StringFields = ExtractFieldsOfType<SomeInterface, string> // "field1" | "field3"
type NumberFields = ExtractFieldsOfType<SomeInterface, number> // "field2"
type ObjectFields = ExtractFieldsOfType<SomeInterface, SomeOtherType> // "field4"
```

### How it works?

First type:

```
type AllowedFieldsWithType<Obj, Type> = {
    [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends Type ? K : never
};
```

1) For each field in object, we check if it extends Type, then we return name of the key as it's type. If not (e.g. we search for `string`, but *field2* is type `number` - we return `never`. It's special type that nothing can be assigned to.

```
AllowedFieldsWithType<SomeInterface, String> equals to: {
  field1: 'field1';
  field2: never;
  field3: 'field3';
  field4: never;
}
```

2) Then we have to filter out `never` properties, we can do it with `Pick`, but for this use case we need only key names.

3) Eventually we use `someType[keyof Obj]` which gather values of given types, skipping never.

I've written article which explains this topic in depth: [Create a condition-based subset types](https://medium.com/@piotrl/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c)

Comment: You don't need the extra pick to filter out the never `A|never=A`. This works just as well type `ExtractFieldsOfType<Obj, Type> = AllowedFieldsWithType<Obj, Type>[keyof Obj]`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes indeed, for this use case we don't have to use `Pick` :) I simplified answer.

Comment: @Piotr Lewandowski, I read your post at https://www.piotrl.net/typescript-condition-subset-types/ and that's awesome, thanks for writing it down. I've noticed that you added a "What this solution won’t solve?" section and I'd like to let you know that I found a way to handle the first item in that list "Nullable subtype"... you check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74272393/how-to-distinguish-different-functions-signature-with-conditional-type-checks/74272675 (specifically the question code) and update your page if you want :)

Comment: @Piotr Lewandowski, in the `null` case we'd do `Condition | null` then... or `Condition | null | undefined` for optional keys that can also be null...