# How to distinguish different functions signature with conditional type checks?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, keyof, function-signature

I'd like to be distinguish the following function types in conditional type checks:

```
type SyncFn = () => void;
type AsyncFn = (data: number) => Promise<void>;
type SyncFnWithArg = (data: number) => void;
```

So I can then use the [KeyOfType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752151/typescript-keyof-returning-specific-type) that [@Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) posted and get the keys within a given interface that match a given type.

I tried the following:

```
type SyncFn = () => void;
type AsyncFn = (data: number) => Promise<void>;
type SyncFnWithArg = (data: number) => void;

interface Foo {
    a?: string;
    b?: number;
    c: number;
    d: string;
    f1?: SyncFn;
    f2?: AsyncFn;
    f3?: SyncFnWithArg;
}

// note: `KeyOfType` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752151/typescript-keyof-returning-specific-type
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V? P: never]: any }

type KeyOfTypeOptionalIncluded<T, Condition> = KeyOfType<T, Condition | undefined>


let onlyStrings: KeyOfTypeOptionalIncluded<Foo, string>;
onlyStrings = 'a' // ✅ working as expected 
onlyStrings = 'b' // ✅ erroring out as expected 
onlyStrings = 'd' // ✅ working as expected 


let onlySyncFn: KeyOfTypeOptionalIncluded<Foo, SyncFn>;
onlySyncFn = 'f1' // ✅ working as expected 
onlySyncFn = 'f2' // ✅ erroring out as expected 
onlySyncFn = 'f3' // ✅ erroring out as expected 

let onlyAsyncFn: KeyOfTypeOptionalIncluded<Foo, AsyncFn>;
onlyAsyncFn = 'f1' // ✅ erroring out as expected 
onlyAsyncFn = 'f2' // ✅ working as expected 
onlyAsyncFn = 'f3' // ✅ erroring out as expected 

let onlySyncFnWithArg: KeyOfTypeOptionalIncluded<Foo, SyncFnWithArg>;
onlySyncFnWithArg = 'f1' //  should error out 
onlySyncFnWithArg = 'f2' //  should error out 
onlySyncFnWithArg = 'f3' // ✅ working as expected
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyiB2BjAYvKBeKAKAlBgfFAG4D2AlgCYDcAsAFCiRQCCAzgimplhQIbC8AXFHgBXALYAjCACc86QgAUZJcWVYQAPKUr5aDcNDhJUAdTLAAFsxkBzDNj4DhYqbPmEd1evTLxgsgBmvIjQyCQkUADe9FBxULwA-MKswDJ+tvrxUJLJIhLSMlnxiC4FssVxFClpGZVQgQCMecac9YEATHlsHKjtAMwtvfDmVjaZ9AC+PnQA9LMiJAHCAAYA0hAgAPKBACqGKw0q4lCWwMBgrILzqSEA1iREQQA2JADuAHSIqrMAjqIQVJkEjwVizAAsAE4AOwAVg6jVhjVmjEBiHSYGAAFo7psSIEsTIIMBRDJ4BksaxIIgyIEyIgsaj6KioBttntDJpdgAaKAANUImFxIHx0SgAG1FFA-FBhaLdglWFBdpKALpQCAADwC8AoSr5iSgihcECeMlVwl48BAUGmdGZhlZmx2+0gW0xwPgvGeAEkkM9RBQIBQubyAMIgigWT2Cp3s11aHlQCO66MgqAAHygol1EDp8GD+Bm9GexKgIOeIBgtXgtiucZdhndwE93r9iADQZD4RIvNS6VrenoFarNbrDgA5LwJ1B5lBAKDkUDeJBkdwyio1mupAQoUEAPBuASP3h-BK9WB+PMBPJDO54vZCpz+XRMAN1rt8H90e6COzxklZeKBvBZF2XVd114JU3wgRAd0-Ys6FLF8f2GYQ2UbN0PRBNt-UDYNNB7XlWlQIdvxPKthknJogIXJcVzXWtXy3aDYMPY9Twoy9Omou8ZAfdcSGfRj313VjSPYkwuCgCdAn6biNV4ld+MEiDN2EuD7QQssRx6CTUOdDkMJbLDfRwrt8IiXkdM4EjtPYCTKMaOT70UhiBJfFSoJgj9RNsjipK42dgNosCGI8pivJEr9fPszjZMCmjnMfNyhOY7yvxLLSyKIkYLGsOw9PjJtMK9EyO1w7sLNgYZRjy2wbKy6rcvGBzqMAXg3AFo9qBWEsATnl3RKnxfDq2PIiSauaziOjazrut6-qFJkQaoGGsTRs4ca7EouLb2C+j7DCtTDyAA)

The problem is that `onlySyncFnWithArg` is being typed as `"f1" | "f2" | "f3"` whereas it should be  `"f3"`....

[image]

---

I also noticed that if I modify `AsyncFn` and remove its argument then I have more problems since the type definition for `onlySyncFn` is now incorrect since now it's `"f1" | "f2"` instead of only being `"f1"` as it is in the first TS Playground above.

[Second TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyiB2BjAYvKBeKAKAlBgfFAG4D2AlgCYDcAsAFCiRQCCAzgimprgVAAoAnEgFsyrCAB5SlfLQbhocJKgDqZYAAtmAgOYZsFAIbBDALijwArsIBGEAXnSFp1evTLxg9gGaHE0ZBISKABveigIqEMAfnNWYAEPHTlIqBtYi2s7ARTIxHMrW3tciIo4hKSSqG8ARgylTirvACYMtg5UJoBmeo74NU1tZPoAXzc6AHoJixIvcwADAGkIEAB5bwAVBXnqoWEoDWBgMFZTKfi-AGsSIh8AGxIAdwA6RBEJgEdLCHiyEnhWBMACwATgA7ABWZo1CE1CaMH6IRJgYAAWkuKxI3lRAggwEsAngSVRrEgiDI3jIiFRCPoCKgyzWmwUEg2ABooAA1QiYDEgLGhKAAbT4UA8UD5Ao2UVYUA2IoAulAIAAPLzwCiyznRfgFCC3AQK8yGeAgKBjOh0hQMlbrLaQVYov7wQx3ACSSDulgoEAorI5AGF-hR1M6eTamfbJOyoEGNaH-lAAD5QSwaiCU+C+-Djeh3PFQf53EAwCrwHSnCN2hSO4DO10exBen1+wIkDnxRLl2T0IslssV-QAckMQ6gUyggFByKCPEgCS5JGXKlVkrwUKCAHg3AJH7vfgxdLXcHmCHNjHE+n9iEh8LlmAS9Vq99m53dD7B6SsuPFDP02ns-ni6GLKD4QIga7PrmdD5neb59OYjLVg6Tr-A2nrer6EhthyDSoD2r57iWfTDrUP5TjOc4LuW94rqB4Hbru+5EceLSkYAvBuALR7UCsBoJCWHc66XnON53hxDGEcoXBQEO3hdKRF4CFei68XeQHLo+670ZaUEFn27QSfBtrMkhdYoe6aEtphQQcnpnB4bp7AScRNRycqClzkpt7UepEH4cWNmoMRzQuf+lF6KpIFgU+mn2UxUkyS5gnXspXm0VFL55jpBE4f06haLoBmRjWyEumZTboa2VmwH0Ax5TodlZdVuVDE5bGcdxvH8a5V7CVAom+eJnA1c1zFBeO0wcVxPF8QJbkCD1fWwRJQ26MRsljWRIWAcBNGRRpW5AA)

I **guess** that's related with how function overloading in typescript is done, but I don't really know, so that's why I'm reaching out for help.... maybe it's not related, but are we able to do such function type distinction in TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be addressed by changing the `KeyOfType` type as follows:

1. Check both directions of the type relationship (`A extends B` and `B extends A`):
2. Wrap the types used in the conditional type clause in tuples (`[A] extends [B]`).

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
  [P in keyof T as [T[P]] extends [V]
    ? [V] extends [T[P]]
      ? P
      : never
    : never
  ]: any
}
```

---

Find a playground example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyiB2BjAYvKBeKAKAlBgfFAG4D2AlgCYDcAsAFCiRQCCAzgimplhQIbC8AXFHgBXALYAjCACc86QgAUZJcWVYQAPKUr5aDcNDhJUAdTLAAFsxkBzDNj4DhYqbPmEd1evTLxgsgBmvIjQyCQkUADe9FBxULwA-MKswDJ+tvrxUJLJIhLSMlnxiC4FssVxFClpGZVQgQCMecac9YEATHlsHKjtAMwtvfDmVjaZ9AC+PgZMABoOrWYW1nZQEAAeAfAUrLDDUIlQaaLQwsEANhr69IzQANIQIADygQAqhppvADRQAGqETAAayeJEC0SgAG1FFA-FAQSAwVA3gk9pC3tCALqY9ZbCA7NF-HFHSFE3HbXZQjGKbGHKAwlwQIiyKCM5kyTHCXjwEBQaZ0W6GKCPF7vQzPMDAMgkeC8C4ASSQF1EFAgFC+vwAwjKKBZpfBAcKnq8PpANVBtTs9TKoAAfKCiHYQQJ+NX4Gb0C4QYBQGUXEAwWrwWysYQik3iyX6uWKxDK1Xq8IkX6pdLBvT0P0BoMhhwAcl4eagAHpi1BAKDkUAA7iQZECMqjcZBEAEKFBADwbgEj9zPwf2BtO5zB5yRF0sV9YyFQD32iH28PabZutjvduhZ-sZPZDiijsuVmt1hvzpsQFtqlceuhen3r4Zh41iyASqUymNKlVqzRJ35LA36W8mFwUB5k0u7jge9bBo2i6nsuXY9n2BxDp0YGVrIU4NiQs7QRsS7nvBa69gGSHAYE-SoROGFQVhc4LrhsH4aunrer6RE9IB96iqaEDPtGCrvgmX4RL87GcBmhH+qJqD5qBJZ7pRtaYdhx4wWebYEVmUlASBHQURBR50Xh6mrpp7CATJ5FyeO6GKdRymGQxxkzNerGIYBoyrLYnERk+UavvxcYfomwn7O5KzjOJAGcB54wyY0YE2dONE4UZF4ScRYVjGsyG6VZiVKbRJ5qWlUXLFl9jIZZY77rWkH2Cp9HFV2QA), and an interesting discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024) about various ways to test for type equality (each with their own caveats).

Comment: oh... that makes sense!! and that's completely new to me (checking both directions)! thank you so much! 