# Why doesn't [number | string] extends [number] | [string] in typescript?

Tags: typescript

These are true:

```js
type A = [boolean | string] extends [boolean] | [string] ? true : false // true
type B = [number | boolean] extends [number] | [boolean] ? true : false // true
type C = [1 | string] extends [1] | [string] ? true : false // true
```

But this is false:

```js
type D = [number | string] extends [number] | [string] ? true : false // false
```

1. How does the TypeScript compiler deal with a tuple type in a condition? Does it distribute one tuple into many tuples?
2. Why is type D `false`?

Comment: that's an interesting observation. Although in practice, arrays of length exactly 1 are not very useful.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey On the contrary, one-element tuples are extremely useful in defining TypeScript types. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74272675/3558960).

Comment: Looks like it's not just numbers, `let x!: [object] | [string]; let z!: [object | string]; x = z;`, results in `Type '[string | object]' is not assignable to type '[string] | [object]'.`
Maybe the first three worked because `1` only consists of one possibility, and `boolean` only consists of two possibilities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before TypeScript 4.0, all of those conditional types evaluated to `false`.  The issue here has to do with how the compiler treats [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) with [union-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) properties differently when the union in question is or is not considered the type of a *discriminant* of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Since TypeScript 3.2 introduced support for [non-unit types as discriminants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants), a union can be a discriminated union as long as *some* common member of the union has a property of a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) (or a union of such types).

The types `boolean | string` and `number | boolean` are acceptable discriminant properties, since `boolean` is shorthand for the union `true | false`, each of which is a literal type.  `1 | string` is also an acceptable discriminant, since `1` is a literal type.  On the other hand,  `number | string` is not an acceptable discriminant type, since neither `number` nor `string` is a literal type.

---

In general, TypeScript does not consider an object type with a union typed property assignable to a union of object types.  That is, unions do not in general propagate upward from properties to top-level objects:

```
const x: { a: RegExp | Date } = { a: Math.random() < 0.5 ? /abc/ : new Date() };
const y: { a: RegExp } | { a: Date } = x; // error!
```

This behavior can be annoying, especially in situations where the type you're trying to assign to is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  So TypeScript 3.5 introduced support for ["smarter" union type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) via [microsoft/TypeScript#30779](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30779) where you can do such assignments as long as the target type is a discriminated union.  So the following assignment works as of TypeScript 3.5:

```
const v: { a: RegExp | "abc" } = { a: Math.random() < 0.5 ? /abc/ : "abc" };
const w: { a: RegExp } | { a: "abc" } = v; // error in TS3.4-, okay in TS3.5+
```

Since `"abc"` is a literal type, then the type of `w` is a discriminated union, and therefore the assignment is accepted.

From TypeScript 3.5 through TypeScript 3.9, those conditional types still all evaluated to `false`, because this change in assignability was not fully reflected in the type system, such as when you write conditional types.  The fix to this, [microsoft/TypeScript#39393](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39393), was released with TypeScript 4.0.  Now the type system also sees that objects-with-union-properties are assignable to appropriate discriminated unions:

```
type A = [boolean | string] extends [boolean] | [string] ? true : false 
// false in TS3.9-, true in TS4.0+
type B = [number | boolean] extends [number] | [boolean] ? true : false 
// false in TS3.9-, true in TS4.0+
type C = [1 | string] extends [1] | [string] ? true : false 
// false in TS3.9-, true in TS4.0+
type D = [number | string] extends [number] | [string] ? true : false 
// false
```

One-tuples like `[X]` are similar to object types like `{0: X}`, so `[X] | [Y]` is a discriminated union if `{0: X} | {0: Y}` is. And since `boolean | string` and `number | boolean` and `1 | string` are discriminant types, the assignment succeeds.  And since `number | string` is not a discriminant type, the assignment fails.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaAjA9mgNhAhgOygB8oBnYAJwEs8BzAXSggA9gI8ATE5dLXPB4kjJVaDAPxQKAV2gAuKADMcmEtAD0axctVRqUACoBlAMwA6AJwBaADSTyM3QSMAWUwAYA1AFgAUKEhQAEIIyHhSALYoEOREUDzY+AzMrBxcSGGR0QLcGAn8UBLScloq6ppKpY4GJhY2dg56Lu7efuDQAMIhSACMscLU9IwsbJzI3dlCFAPi9cUVOholOo01VrZFVU2evv7QACJdGVExxP2iQymj6RHHE2eDhfZz2mVLEL6+AMZoeGRQTPIAN5QHDyABKEBoAFEmGBYnscKwoABfELA0FQACyiIAFqZyPh2GhwgAKACUUAAPFA3KYAKwFKBqHAoT6aeR4CAAdygCNY5JRAG4vj8-iAgSDwZCYXDUcR0fI+dBUYgmIKmZpouQ0OQAIQfHzfX7AKAANwlGIh0NhsQARCzPraUWjJVjcfjCcSBdTaQyJMzWeyoPbWU7kcLDaKTVyLVLrbLYgrgw6wyFTerFlqdZsas46mgANY4EA5sx0jxAA)

[Playground link to code v3.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaAjA9mgNhAhgOygB8oBnYAJwEs8BzAXSggA9gI8ATE5dLXPB4kjJVaDAPxQKAV2gAuKADMcmEtAD0axctVRqUACoBlAMwA6AJwBaADSTyM3QSMAWUwAYA1AFgAUKEhQAEIIyHhSALYoEOREUDzY+AzMrBxcSGGR0QLcGAn8UBLScloq6ppKpY4GJhY2dg56Lu7efuDQAMIhSACMscLU9IwsbJzI3dlCFAPi9cUVOholOo01VrZFVU2evv7QACJdGVExxP2iQymj6RHHE2eDhfZz2mVLEL6+AMZoeGRQTPIAN5QHDyABKEBoAFEmGBYnscKwoABfELA0FQACyiIAFqZyPh2GhwgAKACUUAAPFA3KYAKwFKBqHAoT6aeR4CAAdygCNY5JRAG4vj8-iAgSDwZCYXDUcR0fI+dBUYgmIKmZpouQ0OQAIQfHzfX7AKAANwlGIh0NhsQARCzPraUWjJVjcfjCcSBdTaQyJMzWeyoPbWU7kcLDaKTVyLVLrbLYgrgw6wyFTerFlqdZsas46mgANY4EA5sx0jxAA)

[Playground link to code v3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaAjA9mgNhAhgOygB8oBnYAJwEs8BzAXSggA9gI8ATE5dLXPB4kjJVaDAPxQKAV2gAuKADMcmEtAD0axctVRqUACoBlAMwA6AJwBaADSTyM3QSMAWUwAYA1AFgAUKEhQAEIIyHhSALYoEOREUDzY+AzMrBxcSGGR0QLcGAn8UBLScloq6ppKpY4GJhY2dg56Lu7efuDQAMIhSACMscLU9IwsbJzI3dlCFAPi9cUVOholOo01VrZFVU2evv7QACJdGVExxP2iQymj6RHHE2eDhfZz2mVLEL6+AMZoeGRQTPIAN5QHDyABKEBoAFEmGBYnscKwoABfELA0FQACyiIAFqZyPh2GhwgAKACUUAAPFA3KYAKwFKBqHAoT6aeR4CAAdygCNY5JRAG4vj8-iAgSDwZCYXDUcR0fI+dBUYgmIKmZpouQ0OQAIQfHzfX7AKAANwlGIh0NhsQARCzPraUWjJVjcfjCcSBdTaQyJMzWeyoPbWU7kcLDaKTVyLVLrbLYgrgw6wyFTerFlqdZsas46mgANY4EA5sx0jxAA)